# Laplacian of reciprocal of square of r

Tags: vector-analysis

What is $I=\nabla ^2 \left (\dfrac{1}{r^2}\right )$ where $r$ is the radial coordinate? As $\nabla ^2 \left (\dfrac{1}{r}\right )=-4\pi \delta(r)$ does it mean that $I\propto \delta(r)$? Given $r^2=x^2_1+x^2_2+x^2_3+x^2_4$.

Comment: You work in $\mathbb{R^n}$ with $n=?$

Comment: You have added $r^2=x^2_1+x^2_2+x^2_3+x^2_4$. Thus you consider the issue in $\mathbb{R}^4$. Why don't you say you do not work in one of the usual spaces $\mathbb{R}^2$ or $\mathbb{R}^3$ ?

Comment: Just a simple slip of memory. Sorry.